# ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'open' of undefined

Tags: javascript, angular

With Angular 6 I am calling on API in a service and then subscribing to the service in my controller. I successfully get back data, however I would like to restructure that data in my controller so I can get pass it into a Chart JS chart later on.

Here is my code I have put in a method inside my controller witch I then call in the OnInit method:

```
getStockData() {
  this.stocksService.getStockData()
    .subscribe(
      (response) => {
        for(var i = 0; i <= response.length; i++) {
          this.stockOpen.push(response[i]['open']); // Error points to this line
          console.log('Data: ', response[i]['open']); //This works
        }
      },
      (error) => console.error(error)
    );
}
```

I know at least part of this is working because I am successfully consoling the data from within the for loop, however I then get an error that I can't seem to figure out because when I console `response[i]['open']` it works but when I try to push it into `this.stockOpen` I get the error.

Seems to me that the `push` method is the problem, but I can't seem to figure out how to do it correctly or a different way.

Here is the error:

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'open' of undefined
    at SafeSubscriber._next (alpha.component.ts:26)
    at SafeSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub (Subscriber.js:195)
    at SafeSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.SafeSubscriber.next (Subscriber.js:133)
    at Subscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber._next (Subscriber.js:77)
    at Subscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.next (Subscriber.js:54)
    at MapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/operators/map.js.MapSubscriber._next (map.js:41)
    at MapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.next (Subscriber.js:54)
    at XMLHttpRequest.onLoad (http.js:1055)
    at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:421)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:3748)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `for` loop should be `i < response.length`, not `<=`.

---

With that said, you shouldn't use a for loop if you're just pushing to another array, nor when index doesn't matter. Use a `for...of` loop at the very least: better yet, `[].map` (or if the array is already populated, `[].reduce` with a starting value [or just combine them.])

`this.stockOpen = response.map(item => item.open);`

Comment: Aside from the top portion, this sounds like a bunch of opinions rather than an answer

Comment: Using `map` is an opinion - though a hard one to argue against. Using `for...of` over `for` is pretty inarguable; it's the intended method of looping over every item of an array.

Comment: Except that `for...of` doesnt have the compatibility `for` does

Comment: Plus, you give no reason for using one over another

Comment: Opinion, reason or neither this does give good perspective, I'm coming from Python and Javascript can be pretty confusing so good answer, thank you.

Comment: @cgTag this isnt a place for opinions